# Why use switch in Flux

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux

Why does all Flux (Flux architecture from Facebook) implementation use `switch`?
Why not just import store and use a method reference?
Why use some kind service bus in a browser app?

Answer (score 0):

This allows decoupling of actions from reducers.  When an action is triggered, multiple reducers (through the use of switch statements) can act upon them.

In addition, since actions and reducers are not tightly coupled, they can be easily isolated and unit tested.

However, there is a type of architecture called "ducks" that tightly couples the actions and reducers, you can read more here: https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux

Hope this helps.